# How to handle event of combobox in datagridview?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a checkbox[`All`] and a datagridview as below:

[image]

I would like:

- The inside datagridview, if all checkbox is checked, the checkbox[`All`] is checked and otherwise if all checkbox is unchecked, the checkbox[`All`] is unchecked
- The inside datagridview, there is a checkbox that is unchecked, the checkbox[`All`] is unchecked

I tried it but I am not able to do it:

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool isAllCheck = false;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

            isAllCheck = Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value);
            if (!isAllCheck)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (chkAllItem.Checked && !isAllCheck)
        {
            chkAllItem.Checked = false;
        }

        if (!chkAllItem.Checked && isAllCheck)
        {
            chkAllItem.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        this.dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Any tips on these will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"not able to do it"_ ....what didn't work?

Comment: I apologize for not clearly explaining. "not able to do it" .... means: the inside datagridview, if I uncheck a checkbox, all checkbox is unchecked. However, thanks to the guidance of Mr.TaW as below, I did it run well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `TrueValue`, `FalseValue` and `IndeterminateValue` is a good start.

I found that I also need to do a bit more for this to work; in addition to your `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event I also coded these:

This sets all `CheckBoxCells`:

```
private void cbx_all_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbx_all.Tag == null) for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView.Tag = "busy";
        dataGridView[yourCheckBoxcolumnIndex, i].Value = cbx_all.Checked;
        dataGridView.Tag = null;
    }
}
```

I coded the `CellValueChanged` instead of the `CellContentClick` event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == yourCheckBoxcolumnIndex &&  dataGridView.Tag == null)
    {
       cbx_all.Tag = "busy";
       cbx_all.Checked = testChecks(e.ColumnIndex);
       cbx_all.Tag = null;
    }
}
```

I used the `Tag` property of the `DGV` and the `CheckBox` as a **flag**, that I am busy changing values by code. Some other means to avoid an endless-loop are just as fine.

This is the test function:

```
bool testChecks(int index)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < dataGridView.RowCount; r++)
        if  ( !(bool)dataGridView[index, r].Value ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` has properties `TrueValue`, `FalseValue` and `IndeterminateValue` whose default values are `null`. These are the values given by the property `Value` depending on the state of the checkbox. As `Convert.ToBoolean` converts `null` to `false`, the result of the conversion is always `false` if the properties are not initialized.

These can be initialized on the cell itself or on its owning column.

You need thus to initialize the owning column `TrueValue` to `true` and `FalseValue` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!